# Compile time error: "Cannot convert from B to T1", when working with generics ,constraints and inheritance in C#

Tags: c#, oop, generics, inheritance, constraints

I have a class *B* which has a method *GetSomeB* that returns a new instance of its class:

```
public class B
{
    public B() { }
    public B GetSomeB ()
    {
        return new B();
    }
}
```

I have a class A which works with generics. The generics must be an object of B or of something inherited from B. I however need the types of attributes X and Y in A to be the specific subclass type and not just type B, so I have used generics T1 and T2:

```
class A<T1, T2>
        where T1 : B
        where T2 : B
    {
        public T1 X;
        public T2 Y;

        public A(T1 X, T2 Y)
        {
            this.X = X;
            this.Y = Y;
        }

        public A<T1, T2> GetSomeA()
        {
            return new A<T1, T2>(this.X.GetSomeB(), this.Y.GetSomeB());
        }
 }
```

I am getting compile time errors: **Cannot convert from B to T1** and **Cannot convert from B to T2** from the line in *GetSomeA* method in *class A* How can I work around this?

Comment: If you know (there's no way the compiler can currently) that `GetSomeB` will actually return objects of the right types, insert casts - that's one of their purposes - "I have more information than the compiler about the type of this expression".

Comment: Curently there´s no way `GetSomeB` will ever match the generic constraint, except the generic type `T` is identical to `B`. So if your generic argument would be `C` for instance, `GetSomeB` surely can´t be converted to that generic argument-type, which is `C`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use casts to fix the compile error:

```
public A<T1, T2> GetSomeA() 
{
      return new A<T1, T2>((T1)this.X.GetSomeB(), (T2)this.Y.GetSomeB());
}
```